# batch Only execute for certain extension

Tags: batch-file, rename, file-extension

I don't really have a very deep understanding of what I'm doing here but the thing is I cant make it work for just certain file type

```
FOR %%2 in (*.mp4,*.avi,*mkv) do set fname=%%~n2

FOR %%1 in (*.srt,*.sub) do ( 
    attrib -r %1
    PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > NUL
    cscript "NewReplace.vbs" %1
    ren %1 "%fname%".srt
)
```

So what it DOES is that this is located into %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo and when I Right Click-Send to-MyBatch it searches for a MP4, AVI, MKV in the clicked file directory, copies it's name to my file and appends .srt.

What I WANT IT to do is only accept .srt and .sub files, and when it copies the name to append the original extension not always .srt.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, `FOR %%2...` and similar are errors.

The metavariable (loop-control variable - you've attempted to use `2`) must be alphabets **and** that alphabetic character is case-sensitive (one of the few placs in batch that exhibits case-sensitivity.)

When referencing the value within a `for` loop, use `%%x` (where `x` is your chosen metavariable.)

`%n` where `n` is 1..9 means the parameter `n` provided to the routine, hence `%1` means 'the first parameter given to this routine,' so *thisroutine something somethingelse* would see `something` as parameter 1 and `somethingelse` as parameter 2, referenced by `%1` and `%2` respectively.

Your first line, when corrected, will assign the `name` part of each filename found in turn from the selected masks `(*.mp4,*.avi,*mkv)` and the name part of the very last such name found will be assigned to the variable `fname`.

Similarly, your second `for` loop will look for all `.srt` and `.sub` files, remove any read-only attribute, wait, run your cscript with the entire name (name+extension) of the `*.srt` or `*.sub` found, then attempt to rename that file to *the name found in the first loop*.srt - because that is what you've specified.

The upshot of all this is that the first loop will locate `zzz.mkv` (if that is the last filename found in the first loop) and assign `zzz` to `fname`.

The second loop will rename the first `.srt` or `.sub` file found to `zzz.srt` and since that filename now exists, will fail to rename all of the remaining `.srt` and `.sub` files - including `zzz.srt`.

That's what your code, when the metavariables are fixed, should try to do. It probably isn't what you want it to do, but you've not provided an example, and you've not clearly explained what to do if there are multiple `(*.mp4,*.avi,*mkv)` files or what your `cscript` is supposed to do when provided with a filename, or what you want to do about `srt` and `sub` files

Comment: I'll try do explain better: It is only one srt/sub and one mp4/mkv/avi in a Folder. Right-click on the srt/sub file, Send to, Batch. The batch takes the name of the avi/mkv/mp4 and renames the str/sub file then sends the sub to a script that is replacing some characters inside the sub.